# Using custom IconComponent in MuiSelect with rotation when menu open/closed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material UI gives us a prop to replace the default dropdown icon on the MuiSelect component. However, a custom icon isn't automatically given the same functionality as the default of rotating 180 degrees to visually show when menu is open/closed.

I'm wondering if there is any way to easily add this. I want to globally replace all of the Dropdown icons.

Comment: Custom icons **are** automatically given the same rotation. See my example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59818900/custom-iconcomponent-in-muiselect/59826131#59826131

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thank you for getting back to me! It works with their imported Icons but not with an SVG of my own

Comment: Please share a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem and include that code in your question text.